# How to check (print to stdout) response body created by aiohttp (python 3.6)?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.6, aiohttp

I would like to see my response http body as a response to incoming POST request, which I handle by library aiohttp.web (python 3.6).

```
async def handle(request):
    res = web.Response(body='A body text...')
    print(res.body)       # print body to stdout
    return res
```

`res.body` is some Payload class, which has method *write()*, but *writer* should be specified. It is not clear to me, what is the writer (*sys.stdout*?) and, mainly, how to combine it all together.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.